# JPA /Hibernate - How to define custom join clause on entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, jpa-2.0

I want to join multiple tables to a single column, with additional condition by constant value. Something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Group {
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Resource {
  @Id
  private String id;
  
  private String targetId;

  private String tatgetType;
  
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "targetId", referencedColumnName = "id", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
  // @WhereJoinTable(clause = "target_type = 'USER'")  // just apply for collection
  private User targetUser;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "targetId", referencedColumnName = "id", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
   // @WhereJoinTable(clause = "target_type = 'GROUP'") // just apply for collection
  private Group targetGroup;
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately '@WhereJoinTable' just apply for collection.

I also try '@JoinFormula' but it requires `referencedColumnName`.

Can I implement this scenario with JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a trick, not standard but it works.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula(value = "(SELECT target_id WHERE target_type = 'USER')", 
    referencedColumnName = "id")
private User targetUser;
```